# How to clone a SQL database in Azure Synapse - no menu option, despite being Synapse Administrator

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I'm trying to clone a Synapse Serverless SQL database, so I can test with it.

When I click a SQL database in Synapse Studio, there's no option to clone.

[No 'Clone' option in menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsseE.png)

I am the Synapse Administrator - [Blacked out personal details - it's really me there under 'Synapse Administrator'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbxhz.png)

I don't see MS documentation on how to clone a *SQL Database* in Synapse Serverless.

I do see [MS documentation on how to clone a a *Lake Database* in Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/clone-lake-database). The page shows a 'clone' option when on clicks on the three dots next to a Lake database name.

[But I don't see the 'Clone' option for Lake Databases either](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FpLM.png)

The only caveat in the document is

"Synapse Administrator, or Synapse Contributor permissions are required on the Synapse workspace for creating a lake database."

But again, I am a Synapse Administrator.

I've tried:

- Also adding myself as a Synapse Contributor
- Moving into a new branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried the same In my enviroment.**

- For lake database I am getting a **Clone option when I have Synapse workspace Administrator role to user.**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1TXcYAQ.png]

**To resolve this, try to refresh the browser and delete the cache or try with Privat tab.**

**And for serverless SQL there is no such Option is available** for that you need to try with others method like taking backup and importing it in another database.

Comment: Tried a new browser, as well as clearing cache - still no option to clone Lake database. But, that's kind of a side point / not a concern right now. My main question was about how to clone a SQL database - which OK, not an option, that answers it definitively, thanks.